# Ansible: Share vars between groups

Tags: ansible

Part of my inventory looks like this

```
prod
  group_vars
    all
    rabbit_master
    rabbit_slave
    web_children
    web_master
staging
  group_vars
    all
    rabbit_master
    rabbit_slave
    web_children
    web_master
```

My problem is in my prod inventory, for example, web_master and web_children have pretty much the same variables.

web_children/vars.yml

```
web_master_host: 10.1.1.1
environment: test
key: 123
```

web_master/vars.yml

```
environment: test
key: 123
```

Is there a way I can get web_children to inherit all of the vars from web_master to save duplication?

Comment: Name them distinctly and smack them into `all`. You could also use `vars_files` to include an extra variable file (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#defining-variables-in-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a super group inhabiting the common variables.

- Place the variables in a file e.g. called `web_hosts`
- In your `hosts` file define that the groups `web_master` and `web_children` are children of the `web_hosts` group:

```
[web_master]
…

[web_children]
…

[web_hosts:children]
web_master
web_children
```

For further information, see: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups